# Why can't I whois '.google' domains?

Tags: domain, domain-name, google, whois

I know of only two domains under the TLD `google` (owned by Google, obviously):

```
nic.google
lers.google
```

However, neither of these give valid output when used with `whois`:

```
$ whois nic.google
No whois server is known for this kind of object.
```

Why aren't these domains appearing in `whois`? Which leads to a follow up question, where does `whois` get its data from?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/343941/where-to-find-an-up-to-date-list-of-whois-servers-for-various-tlds

Comment: And: http://superuser.com/questions/758647/how-to-whois-new-tlds

Comment: If what you want to ask is why your client does not work with this tld (as apposed to the q linked above), I think you'll have to share which client, version and any configuration it has. Whois is a mess.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist It's the `whois` client available in the Ubuntu repositories _(Version 5.2.7. Report bugs to <md+whois@linux.it>)_

Answer (score 6):

There's no good reliable starting point for a WHOIS client. It's more or less an "illusion" that you can use `whois` without also specifying the whois server to query.

I'll refer to my answer here https://serverfault.com/a/615848/183318 for the available means of finding the proper WHOIS server for a TLD.
Only the method of querying IANA (WHOIS or [http](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)) is actually reliable but then instead ends you up with a huge blob of text that is relatively expensive to fetch and which also needs to parsed in a possibly semi-fuzzy manner.

Eg

```
$ whois -h whois.iana.org google | grep ^whois
whois:        domain-registry-whois.l.google.com
$
```

Most WHOIS clients seem to instead rely on having a config file primed with the "known" TLDs and some falling back to a DNS lookup for `example.whois-servers.net` (which does not have an entry for `google.whois-servers.net` yet). I don't know how common it is for clients to even attempt a query for `_nicname._tcp.example. SRV`.

Comment: As an addition, the whois server for .google is currently not responding to whois queries. The whois port (43) is not open.

Answer (score 2):

Whois gets it's data from the registrar of the domain your are querying for.

In case of Google's "brand TLD" the registrar is Charleston Road Registry (CRR), CRR is in turn a subsidy of Google.

There's a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/758647/how-to-whois-new-tlds) post with the proper way of configuring your whois client for the new TLDs.

For the google TLD, you would need to query `domain-registry-whois.l.google.com` as it is the whois server holding the registration information for *.google*.

You can look at the *Registry Information* section in the [delegation record here](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/google.html).